# Apache Wink Client in OSGi

Tags: websphere, osgi, apache-wink, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to use the Apache Wink Client in an OSGi application running on WebSphere Liberty Profile 8.5:

```
org.apache.wink.client.ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
org.apache.wink.client.RestClient client = new RestClient(clientConfig);
org.apache.wink.client.Resource resource = client.resource(uri);
org.apache.wink.client.ClientResponse response = resource.get();
System.out.println(response.getEntity(String.class));
```

The compiler produces the following error around the call to ClientResponse.getEntity():

```
The type org.apache.wink.client.internal.BaseRequestResponse cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

It appears that ClientResponse extends org.apache.wink.client.internal.BaseRequestResponse, which is not included in the Export-Package declaration of com.ibm.websphere.appserver.thirdparty.jaxrs.

Is it possible to use the Apache Wink Client from the jaxrs-1.1 feature in an OSGi application?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not authoritative by any stretch, but I've been told directly by an IBMer who works WebSphere Web Services support that those `org.apache.wink.server.internal.*` Wink classes are not accessible and not intended to be accessible.

Comment: That's what I figured. I had a look at the Liberty V.next alpha and the Wink Client is entirely different.  The org.apache.wink.client.internal package has gone away. It seems they might have forked it since this is not reflected in the Apache repository.